# Over 100% disk capacity usage on Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, virtual-machine-manager

In many of my Hyper-V VMs the disk capacity usage is shown in Virtual Machine Manager to be above 100%:

[image]

but inside the VM itself, there is plenty of space left:

[image]

This is the properties page of the HDD:

[image]

How is that even possible? What can I do about it? Should I worry about it?

Comment: I use VMware, so I have to guess: does 157% refer to the current allocation relative to the disc size you set initially, assuming that the disc is configured to be expandable?

Comment: I'm not sure, I can't find anything that references `expandable`, and 40 GB seems to be the Maximum size already

Comment: Have you resolved this or did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this may be based on whether or not your drives are fixed or dynamic volumes. Check those settings and read up on the differences here: http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-guest-design-fixed-vs-dynamic-vhd/

In particular

> Dynamic VHD Benefits
>
> Quick allocation of space. Since a new dynamic VHD contains only
> header and footer information, it is extremely small and can be
> created almost immediately.
>
> Minimal space usage for VM-level backups.
>
> Backup utilities that capture a VM operate at the VHD-level and back
> it up in its entirety no matter what. The smaller the VHD, the smaller
> (and faster) the backup.
>
> Over-commit of hard drive resources. You can
> create 20 virtual machines with 40GB boot VHDs on a hard drive array
> that only has 500GB of free space.
>
> Read more:
> http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-guest-design-fixed-vs-dynamic-vhd/#ixzz3NpQFJQPy